# Can the word "vulnus" mean vulnerability?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'm curious specifically about this line of text from the Aeneid:

"Cum Juno aeternum servans sub pectore vulnus" (When Juno is nursing an eternal wound at the bottom of her heart. Verg.Aen.1.36)

This vulnus obviously refers to the enmity Juno feels for the Trojans. But I'm wondering if this line can be reinterpreted to mean Juno is holding on to a love for the Carthaginians.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot refer either to anything good (save for "wounds of love"), nor to a quality, being a straight and simple equivalent of English "wound, blow".

Answer (score 2):

In the Aeneid, Juno feels great enmity towards the Trojans (not the Greeks) for several reasons.

1. Paris spurned her beauty (Line 27)
2. Ganymede took her place in Jupiter's court (Line 28)
3. The *Parcae* doomed Carthage to fall at the hands of their descendants (Line 22)

Any one of these or all together, I think, is the *vulnus* which Juno nursed. Her love for Carthage is certainly part of this complex, but it is not the whole story.